# Room auto migration: Migration didn't properly handle:

Tags: android-room

I am using room library in my app. I added new column in my entity witch holds list of object. Room can't after migrate this entity. In android studio I got error message Migration didn't properly handle: EntityName. Android studio returns two type of table expected and found.
In found table I did't find my new column.
I am using room 2.4.3 this version is supporting auto migrate but doesn't work

Comment: You have to indicate that you want to use auto migration see https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/AutoMigration. If you still have issues then you will need to edit your question and provide the before and after `@Entity` annotated class(es) and the `@Database` annotated class and the stack trace from the log that at least has the expected and found messages.